# How to use onComplete() function in jquery countTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

So i'm using this [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo) that is counting to a target number when i scroll to an element.

all i want is when the number finishes counting, add **`+`** before it, how can i do it?

**Note:** the [plugin](https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo#options) contains a callback function called `onComplete()` but i don't know how to use it in this script...

Example of what's in my mind:

when the number is **still** counting: **420** *clients*

the number **finished** counting: **+** **5000** *clients*

Here is a working example of my current script:

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
  var elemTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var elemBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

  var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
  return isVisible;
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView(document.getElementById('counters'))) {
    $('.ace-counter-number').countTo();

    // Unbind scroll event
    $(window).off('scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
.justaddheight {
  height: 500px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countto/1.2.0/jquery.countTo.js"></script>

<section class="justaddheight text-center about">
  <h1>SCROLL DOWN</h1>
  <p>First, Scroll Now</p>
  <p>Second, try Again but wait for few seconds before scroll to identify.</p>
</section>
<section class="justaddheight service">

</section>
<section class="justaddheight portfolio">

</section>
<section id="counters">
  <div class="ace-overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-briefcase to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="89" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="100">89</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Finished projects</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-code to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="2343409" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">2343409</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Templates</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-cup to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="1302" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">1302</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Cup of coffees</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-people to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="52" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">52</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Happy clients</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
.countTo({
  onComplete: function() {
    $(this).prepend("+");
  }
});
```

**[`$.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)** inserts content before the target element, and **[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** targets each of the elements in your `countTo` loop (in this case `$('.ace-counter-number')`).

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
  var elemTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var elemBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

  var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
  return isVisible;
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView(document.getElementById('counters'))) {
    $('.ace-counter-number').countTo({
      onComplete: function() {
        $(this).prepend("+");
      }
    });

    // Unbind scroll event
    $(window).off('scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
.justaddheight {
  height: 500px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countto/1.2.0/jquery.countTo.js"></script>

<section class="justaddheight text-center about">
  <h1>SCROLL DOWN</h1>
  <p>First, Scroll Now</p>
  <p>Second, try Again but wait for few seconds before scroll to identify.</p>
</section>
<section class="justaddheight service">

</section>
<section class="justaddheight portfolio">

</section>
<section id="counters">
  <div class="ace-overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-briefcase to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="89" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="100">89</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Finished projects</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-code to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="2343409" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">2343409</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Templates</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-cup to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="1302" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">1302</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Cup of coffees</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-people to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="52" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">52</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Happy clients</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps! :)